# How can I make these "next" and "previous" buttons in timeline to make screen show the next or previous content, not changing the range on top?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to make a horizontal timeline for some kind of info about Covid-almanac. I found [this](https://codepen.io/kurugenga/pen/WNQMjeX) but the next and previous buttons changes the range of the dates on top, not changing the page content.

Can anyone make this happen?

```
//detect click on the next arrow
        timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].on('click', '.next', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            updateSlide(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'next');
        });
        //detect click on the prev arrow
        timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].on('click', '.prev', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            updateSlide(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'prev');
        });
```